# Где я могу писать программы на Python 3 с интерфейсом?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, python-3.6

Я новичок в **ЯП** **Python**. Второй месяц обучения. Изучил все основы и т.д, хочется большего. **Где** **я могу писать программы на питоне** **с интерфейсом?** Есть ли что то похожее на Visual Basic? Заранее спасибо

Comment: pyqt5, tkinter, pygtk ,wxpython, pyqt4...

Comment: смотря что подразумеваете под основами

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio - я лично там пишу на Python.

Answer (score 2):

В питоне много библиотек для программирования  [GUI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F) :

- [PyQt5](https://python-scripts.com/pyqt5) — надстройка над qt из с/с++
  <sub>[Install pyqt5](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/)</sub>
  ---
- [Tkinter](https://habr.com/ru/post/133337/) — встроенная библиотека на основе [tcl/tk](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tk)
- PyGtk — надстройка на gtk
- WxPython

---

Я лично рекомендую PyQt5

---

#### Update

Для новичков лучше подходит tkinter.

*Nota bene*:  В питоне 3 tkinter с *маленькой* буквы , а в питоне 2 с *большой*.

Comment: PyQt5 является достаточно сложной штукой. Если человек только освоил азы, ему больше подойдет tkinter,а так - да, функционал у  PyQt5 безграничен..

Comment: Да tkinter для новичков лучше. Я сначало довольно долго на нем писал , пока не осточертело:)

Answer (score 2):

Базовая Tkinter.
Можно установить PyQt.
Библиотек для интефейса на самом деле очень много, но мне нравится PyQt. Поищите в интернете. Найдите ту, которая Вам понравится.
Если что, то красивый интерфейс можно сделать на PyQt.

Answer (score 0):

Для обычных приложений с графическим итерфейсом рекомендую **tkinter**. Он очень легкий для освоения и написания, с довольно большим функционалом.

Хочешь писать игры? Если да, то советую обратить внимание на библиотеку **arcade**. Она также очень простая и на писать на ней - одно удовольствие. Есть её более старый и более широкоизвестный аналог - pygame. Но он более сложный; к тому же у **arcade** есть перед ним ряд преимуществ...

*Выбирай*.

Answer (score 0):

Qt Creator - SDK для Qt, поддержка питона не такая как на C++, но приемлимо для работы. Интерфейсы GUI можно подправить мышкой, если создавать отдельным файлом. Встроенная справка.

https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/index.html - Учебник.

https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/index.html - Доки